# How to see how many people are on your site and store as variable?

Tags: php

I've seen many online tools about tracking how many people are currently/have visited a website.

I was wondering how it would be done, so no need for third-party websites. I would like to be able to count how many people are currently on the site, and update it globally to everyone on the site.

Example: Client one goes to my site (currently: 01 user(s) on the site) then Client two connects, now both Clients will have the counter updated (currently: 02 user(s) on the site).

The reason why I'd like it to be stored as a variable is for notifications when a certain amount of people are on the site. Example: There are 50 or more people on the site!

If possible, I'd like to mainly use PHP, SQL and/or JS/jQuery. I'm not really sure where to start with this, but I was thinking of using a Text Document with PHP Updating it and then using `jQuery.load()`

Comment: To do this, you could switch your session system over to a custom handler in PHP, and then store this data in a database. The number of people on a site is then a `COUNT()` of the users seen in the last 10 minutes (or whatever other figure you wish to use).

Comment: Marc's solution on the above link is a bit easier than my suggestion, try that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not unlike a chat room implementation. Whereas a chat room shows all participants, you are interested in only the number of visitors.

One easy way to get started is to use Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/). It is quite interesting in that you don't have to build the infrastructure for storage/real time notifications etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more fundamental--it depends on what you mean by "on the site". If you mean a browser has requested a page, then the answer is technically almost always zero, because once the request has been completed, that person is no longer "on the site".

However, if you mean that just looking at your site "counts", then your question makes sense but the answer is practically impossible to answer correctly for a number of reasons (such as: bots, local caching, proxy cache servers, shared connections, parallel connections, etc.)

However, if you insist on approximating the number of users "actively" using your site, you will need to make some assumptions about how long they might look at a page before "wandering off" to another site or closing the browse/tab or simply walking away. You will also have to make some assumptions about what counts as a user: connection, IP address, session, browser, etc.

Comment: Usually 'on the site' is taken to mean 'seen in the last X minutes'. How long is appropriate might vary - maybe five minutes or so?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (you will have to build the tables yourself but here's the basics).

Create a table on database with 3 columns

Table name: last_seen

```
table columns:
id primary, int(11) auto increment
session_id, varchar(255) unique
timestamp, int(11) (make sure this is indexed as well for fast lookups)
```

Now create a table to house number of online users:

```
table name: online_users

id , int(11) primary, autoincrement
online int(11) index
```

**Now for the code:**

1. set a session for each user with the timestamp of the request using php's `time()`.
   1 a. store session id and timestamp to database.
2. update the session on each request by overwriting the session variable with `time()`
   2 a. update value in database for the users session id.
3. create a cronjob that runs every 1 minute. and runs the following php code
4. create the ajax file to return the json to jQuery
5. write the jQuery

**php cronjob**

```
//cronjob

$mysqli = new mysqli( your connection variables );

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(COUNT *)as online_users FROM FROM last_seen where timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE");
if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $onlineusers = (int)$row['online_users'];
    }
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM online_users WHERE 1;");
    if($query->num_rows == 0){
        //we have to insert
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO online_users (online) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$onlineusers);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }else{
        //we can just update
        $stmt = $myqli->prepare("UPDATE online_users SET online = ? WHERE id='1';");
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$online);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

**AJAX script**

```
   //ajax file
   $mysqli = new mysqli( your connection variables );
   $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT online FROM online_users WHERE id='1';");
   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $result = $row['online'];
   }
   die(json_encode(array('online_users'=>$result)));
```

**jQuery $.getJson**

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('/path/to/ajaxfile.php',function(data){
        var online_users = data.online_users;
        $('#online-users').html(online_users);
    })
})
```

Comment: Hmm pretty interesting solution

Comment: eh, so much for wasting my time answering it.

Answer (score 0):

While technically you could implement it yourself, why would you? Focusing on what adds extra value to a site is most important to those using it.

Use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) instead:

The advantage of doing it through GA is that you save on server resources and don't need to maintain any extra code overhead in doing so. It will track other data over time and you can setup other custom events, e-commerce tracking, goals funnels and a lot more.

**Google Real-Time monitoring:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zY7m5s4SPU

**Google Custom Alerts** can notify you by email or SMS of pre-defined events.

> Create custom alerts to monitor your data for statistical variations
>   that are important to you. For example, you might want to know when
>   bounce rate increases by more than 5% compared to the day before, or
>   when revenue decreases by more than 10% compared to the same day a
>   year ago.
>
> Measure the normal variation over the time periods you use. If a
>   normal fluctuation from one week to another is 5%, then you might want
>   to know when the fluctuation exceeds 6% or 7%.
>
> Getting early notices of changes that might indicate new trends or
>   problems lets you prepare or react appropriately. For example, if
>   there’s a sudden increase in traffic, you can keep an eye on things to
>   see whether it’s an anomaly or the beginning of a trend. If there’s a
>   trend developing, you might need more server capacity or more stock on
>   hand. If bounce rate starts to increase, there might be incongruities
>   between your ads and landing pages, or important calls to action might
>   be obscured by a new design.
>
> Configure your alerts to send email and/or text messages

### Setting up a Custom Alert in Google Analytics:

After you've logged into Google Analytics:

1. Go to *Admin*
2. Then under view (the far right column) select *Custom Alerts*.
3. Click *New Alert*
4. Give it a name, *over 50 visitors*.
5. Apply to *All Visitors*
6. Alert me when *Session*
7. *Is Greater Than*   50

Comment: completely ignorant of current trends in ecommerce. people love to see how many other people are online. fact. its not resource intensive if you use a server side script to precalculate it on a set interval. its pretty cheap to read from databases these days, what with query cacheing and all.

Comment: I must live under a rock, I haven't seen sites flash real-time user vistors since early 2000's. FB does this but it shows you actual socially relevant information, people you know. There is context there. Showing meaningless anonymous visitors on an e-commerce site is like giving statistics to drivers to how many people drove on this road today - nobody cares.

Comment: I subscribe to academic and tech newsgroups, so i'm a bit ahead of the curve. Ebay is supposedly beta testing a new websocket powered platform with a "users browsing this auction" display and real time Q & A with sellers.

Comment: What's old is new again, it doesn't mean it's any better than the original.